# Stylus target Safari only

Tags: css, webkit, stylus

Does anyone know how to translate the following CSS rule to the proper Stylus format? I tried removing the curly braces and semi-colons, but still can't seem to get it to work.

/* Safari 7.1+ */

_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .jw-icon-replay {

position: absolute;

top: 0;

left: 3.75rem;

}

Comment: I fear that this will be impossible inside Stylus. Seems like a very niche CSS usage/hack, simply not covered by this technology.

Comment: What exactly won't work in your case? This example compiles perfectly in the latest Stylus (you can check it by yourself at http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/try.html)